# C++ boost json parser suppress "No such node" output

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way to stop the Boost json parser from outputing "No such node" to the console whenever an invalid child location is passed in?

```
jsonNode.get_child("invalid.node.location");
```

I've tried changing the code to add a second argument for the default and the compiler says that it is an invalid argument

Code Snippet (siteTree is another ptree), the location node is an array when it is available in the JSON:

```
const ptree& test = siteTree.get_child("location", empty_ptree<ptree>());
```

Error 1:

```
Function 'empty_ptree' could not be resolved
```

Error 2:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> & get_child(const boost::property_tree::string_path<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &)
const boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> & get_child(const boost::property_tree::string_path<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &)
boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> & get_child(const boost::property_tree::string_path<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &)
const boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> & get_child(const boost::property_tree::string_path<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &, const boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>> &)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The unary `ptree::get_child` throws on being passed an invalid node. However, the overload taking two arguments takes a default value to return if the path passed is invalid. You could use this overload. Alternatively, `ptree::get_child_optional<T>` returns a `boost::optional<T>`, returning `boost::null` if there the path passed in invalid.

Comment: I tried changing the function and do not see any overloaded method options. Can you provide an example code snippet to demonstrate what you are referring to?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/property_tree/examples/empty_ptree_trick.cpp